# Making a line of code repeat in android every second

Tags: android, repeat

This is the line i want to repeat.

```
     handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 1);
```

This app is a tycoon app and so the user can buy upgrades and if they tap the button the get $$ and so when they buy upgrades keeping the value up-to-date is required.

```
package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button myButton;
private int Counter = 0;
private Button myButton2;
private TextView myTextView;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private int Test = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 1);
        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {
                ButtonCounter(Counter);
            }
        });
        myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
   public int ButtonCounter(int Counter){
   Counter+=1;
   return Counter;
    }

public int AutoCounter(int Counter, int add) {
    Counter+=add;
    return Counter;
}

public void Display(int Counter, TextView myTextView) {
    String man = String.valueOf(Counter);
    myTextView.setText("$" + man);
}

private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something here on the main thread
        Counter = AutoCounter(Counter,Test);
        Display(Counter, myTextView);

    }
    };


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 1);
```

call that line inside `onResume()` method. Make sure your show an `AlertDialog` to the user whenever he or she hits the button to get $$. Since the `AlertDialog` pops up everytime the user tries to buy $$. `onResume()` will be called.

Comment: wouldn't this only work when the user presses the button

Comment: thats fine. if you update continuously battery will drain..You need to use broadcast receiver for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  

    private void startAnimation() {
           countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(700, 500) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                 //your code to repeat
                    }
                    start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

Comment: you can set the time as per your requirement

Comment: it says cannot resolve countdowntimer and also start(); has an error in which it says return type required and .start(); says the same

Comment: private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;  take this as global variable.